# Turning this specific example of an implicit solution to a differential equation to an explicit solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you turn this implicit solution to a DE into an explicit solution (basically solve for y). 
$$
\frac{y-2}{y+2} = e^{4x+c_{2}}
$$

The book came up with this answer:
$$
y = 2\frac{1+ce^{4x}}{1 - ce^{4x}}
$$

Comment: Solve $\frac{y-2}{y+2} = z$ for $y$ in terms of $z$.

Comment: If it helps, $c=e^{c_2}$

Comment: $\frac{y-2}{y+2} = 1 - \frac{4}{y+2}$.

Comment: welcome, user71181. When you receive a helpful answers, we encourage you to *accept* an answer (you can accept only one answer per question asked). You can accept an answer by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. As a bonus to you, you get 2 reputation points for each question that you accept an answer for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{y-2}{y+2} = e^{4x + c_2} $$

$$ y-2 = (y+2)e^{4x + c_2} $$

$$ y-2 = y\,e^{4x + c_2} + 2\,e^{4x + c_2} $$

$$ (1 - e^{4x + c_2})\,y = 2\,(1 + e^{4x + c_2}) $$

$$ y = 2\frac{1 + e^{4x + c_2}}{1 - e^{4x + c_2}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Start by multiplying both sides by $y+2$, then solve for $y$.